# How to pop to root after double tapping a tab bar item?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uitabbar

Normally when a `UINavigationController` is placed in a `UITabBarController` the navigation controller pops to root with the respective tab it is in is double tapped. How do I achieve the same effect with a `UISplitViewController` is between the tab bar controller and the navigation controller? Ideally it would recurse through the view controller's child view controllers and calling `popToRootViewController` on all navigation controllers that it finds. Do I have to add my own gesture recognizer to the tab bar since it doesn't look like there is a hook for knowing when a user has double tapped a tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting up a `UIGestureRecognizer` I simply keep track of the selected index in `shouldSelectViewController` and popped to root on my master navigation controller in `didSelectViewController` if the old selected index was the same as the new one.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4, it can go something like this:

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    private var shouldSelectIndex = -1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        shouldSelectIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
        return true
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if shouldSelectIndex == tabBarController.selectedIndex {
            if let splitViewController = viewController as? UISplitViewController {
                if let navController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as? UINavigationController {
                    navController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```